# Is it possible to make divs behave like tables in IE6 using only CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to make divs behave like tables in IE6 using only CSS and HTML?
*Using display:table, table-row, or table-cell doesn't work in IE6*

If it's possible, what are some approaches?

Comment: You answered yourself -- IE6 doesn't support those values, and that's the only way using CSS. Or maybe you should clarify what exactly you mean by "behave like tables".

Comment: Yeah you should definitely clarify. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible (without using CSS for positioning, sizing, etc. which you won't want)

Comment: @Babiker: yeah, but what I'm talking about would be **really** horrible.  Taking a heap of elements and positioning and sizing them manually by CSS just as you might make a CSS layout. And if you have overlap, or need dynamic size... forget it.